# How does Healing Hymn interact with Darts of Life?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

The errata of Healing Hymn states:

> the +1 bonus is limited by the maximum caster level bonus of a curing spell. For example, if a level 10 cleric cast cure serious while under the effect of healing hymn used by a bard with 10 ranks in perform, the cure serious spell would only cure 3d8+15 instead of 3d8+20.

Darts of Life (Complete Champion, p. 118) has no *maximum caster level bonus*, it just creates 10 darts that heal 1d8 hp each.

It could be either no increase from Healing Hymn, or no limit to the increase.

Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that *healing hymn* is horribly ambiguous, even post-errata, about what it actually does

> An affected ally who casts any conjuration (healing) spell gains a +1 [...] bonus on **the roll** for each rank you have in the Perform skill.

<sup>(*Complete Champion* pg. 47, **emphasis** mine)</sup>

It is really un-obvious what “the roll” is supposed to be here. The example of *cure serious wounds* from the errata suggests that we’re talking about rolling to see how much is healed, but even that is unclear when you talk about something like *darts of life*, which involves multiple rolls. It is plausible to read *healing hymn* as affecting all, just one, or even none of them—since you don’t actually make any of those rolls while casting, but as part of a free action taken after the spell resolves.

There is no real way, by the rules as written, to resolve this.

Meanwhile, there is the separate question of whether or not the lack of CL-based scaling on the healing from *darts of life* indicates an implicit +0 limit. There, I think we can be more sure—it does not. Really, if the errata’s version of things were the intent all along, the bonus should have been to the spell’s caster level, rather than to “the roll.” That would be clear and unambiguous (and would definitively provide no bonus to *darts of life* and other healing spells that do not scale by caster level). But that isn’t what they wrote, they indicate a bonus on “the roll” that cannot allow that roll to exceed any stated limitations. Since *darts of life* does not state any limitation, there is no problem for the bonus.

All in all, it doesn’t really matter because *healing hymn* is pretty garbage. In a very quick-paced game where it truly mattered how quickly you were up and ready for the next fight, it could be valuable, but in most games that kind of situation is a distinct rarity. It doesn’t really matter if your cleric zaps a *wand of cure light wounds* for 5½ average hp per round or 9½ average hp per round, which is basically what *healing hymn* amounts to. (If you were thinking that you’d be saving charges on the wand by having each one do double duty, consider that a *wand of lesser vigor* heals 11 hp per charge—it takes a minute, but that’s still better even than *healing hymn* can offer to *cure light wounds*. And since *lesser vigor* has no roll, *healing hymn* doesn’t apply to it. So again it just becomes a question of time.) *Fascinate* may be an exceedingly situational ability, but when it comes up it is **awesome**. *Healing hymn* is never awesome.

(Also, for that matter, *darts of life* is also useless—it’s a *5th-level spell* that burns multiple actions to heal a small amount. Not a good use of a spell slot at all.)

Comment: Also, healing hymn does not affect heal spells cast by magic items.

Comment: @JoshuaD Fair enough, missed/forgot that line when I discussed the wands. Only makes the feature even more useless, though.

Comment: Given that it replaces fascinate -- a feature that doesn't have many alternative options and is actually useless (as long as you can swap out suggestion at level 6 as well) -- I tend to like healing hymn as an option for bards.  If all it did was double healing at night, it would be better than fascinate IMO. In my campaign we've been using the non-errrata'd version and I've been happy with it as another tool in the toolbox. The errata makes the first feature pretty lame, though. I agree.

Comment: @JoshuaD *Fascinate* is absolutely not useless; it’s certainly niche, but when its time to shine comes, it’s brilliant. And since *healing hymn* doesn’t affect items—which should be the source of 99% or more of your hp healing—it’s not worth the space it takes on your character sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Darts of Life explicitly states that each dart behaves like a *cure* spell.

> Each dart heals 1d8 points of damage the target has taken, as though it were a *cure* spell.

(Complete Champion, p118)

As each dart behaves like a separate *cure* spell, each dart would be affected by Healing Hymn independently.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] when you get a chance, and visit the [help] for more information. This is a really good first answer, thanks for contributing and happy gaming!